# Fragment Navigation Drawer - findViewById in MainActivity returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an Android view with the Navigation Drawer.

I can't add items in my listview in fragment.

my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
android:clickable="true"
tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />
```

In MainActivity.java, in onCreate() i call this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    //This is not working but it should
    createLateral();
}

private void createLateral(){
    ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuLaterale);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

It gives me exception because findViewById(R.id.drawerlist) returns null. How can I resolve?

Comment: Is `driver` in `fragment_navigation_driver.xml` a typo?

Comment: mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)  
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);  try to find view in fragment

Comment: Yes it is. I fix it and I add full onCreate() code

Comment: i tried mNavigationDrawerFragment.findViewById(R.id.drawerlist) but it says that i can't call findViewById on that component

Comment: You should move the `createLateral()` method to the `NavigationDrawerFragment` and call it in the Fragments `onCreateView()` method

Comment: I made it but I cannot call the findViewById method

Comment: It's `view.findViewById()`